# Corrupt internal APFS Catalina disks can’t boot & be removed

Tags: catalina, apfs, disk-format

Internal disk (disk0 & disk1 APFS) and internal PCIe (disk2 & disk3 APFS) are corrupted.

Currently booting from an external usb thumb drive (disk4 & disk5 APFS) and I can’t seem to erase/format my bad Catalina install; which I’ve spent hours trying to debug.

I’m trying Terminal & Disk Utility apps with zero success.

````
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         2.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume FolkiMac2TB - Data      1.1 TB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume FolkiMac2TB             11.2 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         121.0 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.0 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume Preboot                 86.1 MB    disk3s2
   2:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.8 MB   disk3s3
   3:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk3s4
   4:                APFS Volume PCIe 128GB              11.0 GB    disk3s5

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *30.8 GB    disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         30.5 GB    disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +30.5 GB    disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume 30GB-APFS-Catalina -... 4.0 GB     disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 85.6 MB    disk5s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.9 MB   disk5s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 MB     disk5s4
   5:                APFS Volume 30GB-APFS-Catalina      11.1 GB    disk5s5

folkusbthumb@Jasons-MBP ~ % ```
````

Comment: Which Mac model are you using?  What version of macOS are you using?  Was it your intention to have two different APFS containers on two different drives?  Was this working before?

Comment: Rather than continue to debit this, are you open to erasing it all to get a clean install?